# Centering responsive DIVs within a container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web

If you resize the screen the `div`s are responsive and move. When the right hand div drops below, it leaves space to the right of the screen. I want all the `div`s to automatically center instead of staying to the left

I created this JSFiddler to help explain but it doesn't allow me to post with message. Will post below.

Any help?

Comment: JSFiddler to help explain: http://jsfiddle.net/Tc33k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using floats and centering is very difficult. Try using `display:inline-block` instead and add `text-align:center` on the wrapping parent.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc33k/4/)

***Amended* CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center; /* add this */
}

.box-container { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    //float: left; /*tremove this */
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
    margin: 50px 5px 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 185px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #BBBBBB;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
```

}

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much