# Position the divs in the center of the container in every window width

Tags: html, css

I came with a design feature I want to add to my website. I have a container that hold informations about user.The container holds dynamically created divs,this means that in every user account the number of divs changes. My main goal is to add responsive style so my container hold exactly the same number of divs in every device width, positioned in the center.

### Problem

The problem is in the horizontal align of the divs. Look in the next images:

[image]

If we have a width of 768px then the interface looks as expected

If we resize the window to eg. 850px width then the results are the following:

[image]

You see that the divs aren't positioined in the center of the screen so that a blank space is created. Moreover it should appear one more div as the width of the page expanding if we have the appropriate space to hold one more div in the line. Now think that there could be many  rows not just or two. And every column should position the elements in the same place.

I know that my explanation isn't the greatest so if you have any questions please ask.

How can I fix the css rules to cender my divs in the different window widths?

My css file is the following:

```
/* CONTAINER */
.seas {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* THE INNER BOXES DIVS */
.sea {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

The html file

```
 <div class="seas" id="seas">
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
 <div>
```

#### Update - (Not) Possible Duplicate -

To answer for the duplicate tag, this question is not duplicate. I understand if you think that it is, cause my question is referring to a more advance web design style than the majority of questions here.I had hard time myself to describe what I wanted. Anyway I found the solution on my own , and thanks to the answer were posted.

Comment: Rather go for fluid design. Use `%` for width and it'll be fine. If this step is OK, I can give you solution

Comment: Can you add your HTML

Comment: @BikasVaibhav I'm new student of web design so if you please write more details. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pugazh as you wish but I use jquery to dynamically create the divs as explained

Comment: Where is the HTML ??

Comment: @GeorgeGkas essentially, you're setting width and margins in pixels, change them to % and it'll be fluid design. Then UI will adjust automatically with screen size

Comment: @BikasVaibhav can you add your solution?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas added my solution. Have a look and try resizing it as much as you want.

Comment: Is **[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/w3n3oo5q/)** what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering responsive DIVs within a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914254/centering-responsive-divs-within-a-container) and a host of other similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on our conversation, I'm adding one fluid design solution, you can look here

http://jsbin.com/rohoqolapa/1/edit?output

All CSS you need is following

```
/* CONTAINER */
.seas {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* THE INNER BOXES DIVS */
.sea {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

**EDIT:** - Since changing width is not required and content needs to be center aligned, basically this might be the solution

http://jsbin.com/hapeqerosi/1/edit?output

All you have to do is to change parents css -

```
.seas {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Your parent div `.seas` is actually block level element, so you should rather align all it's child centrally.

Comment: I don't want the width of the inner boxes to change. This is twhy I asked for help.

Comment: nope, as I described I want every column to align vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You should add text-align:center to parent .seas so the inner .sea with display:inline-block; to cover the white space .

```css
.seas {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

/* THE INNER BOXES DIVS */
.sea {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  background-color:Red;
  vertical-align:top
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .sea {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="seas" id="seas">
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
      <div class="sea homeWindow"> </div>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/w3n3oo5q/4/)**

I think it's what you want

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
}    
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}    
.wrapper>div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}    
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 200px;
  }
}    
@media (min-width: 401px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 400px;
  }
}    
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 600px;
  }
}    
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 980px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 90%;
    }
    .sea {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 970px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .sea {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 80%;
    }
    .sea {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 770px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 80%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 85%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    .seas {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```