# Centering a row with margin between cols

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wrapper

I have 6 divs I want to show in my website, and i want a margin between them for the look. To make the margin I had to set the width on the cols, else the design would break when changing the width of the site. My question is: how do I center all the cols? I've tried with a wrapper, but with no luck.

This is my html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron">

        <h2>Header</h2>
    <div class="row" id="steps">

        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>1</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>2</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>    

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>3</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>4</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>     

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>5</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <p>6</p>
                <li></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#steps { 
text-align: center;
}

#steps div {
width: 320px;
margin: 2px;
line-height: 22px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
height: 110px;  
}

#steps li {
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#steps p {
color: #1d70b7;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering responsive DIVs within a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914254/centering-responsive-divs-within-a-container)

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children..not divs. ***Validate***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Lists in rows in bootstrap, it is better to use approach below.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="col-md-6">Content1</li>
        <li class="col-md-6">Content2</li>
        <li class="col-md-6">Content3</li>
        <li class="col-md-6">Content4</li>
        <li class="col-md-6">Content5</li>
        <li class="col-md-6">Content6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the list and take this approach:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/o7j93wju/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div class="row" id="steps">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="list-unstyled">
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>4</p>
          </div>
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>5</p>
          </div>
          <div class="l-u col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <p>6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#steps {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.list-unstyled {
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.l-u {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0.5%;
  line-height: 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  height: 110px;
}
.l-u p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #1d70b7;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```